# How to disable landscape mode of Android libraries from main Android app

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, orientation

I have an app that uses a 3rd library. In my main app, I disabled all activityies to be in landscape, but once the app goes to the Activity inside the 3rd library, it allows the screen to be in landscape mode.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Is there anyway I can disable it from the main App?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`from all activities in your manifest and set it only in your application XML tag.

```
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
......
.....
...
..
.
</application>
```

If you want to have certain activities within your app to be both landscape and portrait, then you can override the screenOrientation attribute within the specific activity that you want to be both portrait and landscape.

Comment: I don't think android:screenOrientation can be applied to application tag, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I see. I believe that the 3rd party library activity does not need to be declared in the manifest, correct? Can you declare and override its orientation?

Comment: yeah I mean how can I overwrite it, because there are actually few activities inside the 3rd libraries and I cannot access to its code